# Make date with string MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to make a date with string but I have a problem with the string  concatenation, I do that :

```
@MyVariable ='1'+ ' '+@month +' '+year(now)
```

But this is not work so i tried to use something like that:

```
CAST(year(now()) as CHAR(4))
```

But always the same issue. It is a real problem because i can't use the STR_TO_DATE function.

My sql query:

```
SET @Month = month(TIMESTAMPADD(month, -1, CAST(now() as DATE)));
Set @firstDay = STR_TO_DATE('1'+ ' '+@month +' '+year(now),"%d %M %Y");
SET @lastDay = last_day(TIMESTAMPADD(month, -1, CAST(now() as DATE)));
SELECT count(*) AS M1 FROM DATE where CAST(DATE_CREATION as DATE) 
BETWEEN @firstDay and @lastDay;
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: I prefere to set such vars with your other languages, like PHP, Python or what ever, when you generate your query. Otherwise try `CONCAT("SQL ", "Tutorial ", "is ", "fun!")` to combine Vars.

Comment: + is an arithmetic function in mysql are you sure you are using mysql and not sqlserver. If mysql use concat instead.

Comment: In Mysql `+` is not the concatenation operator. Use concat()

Comment: Which kind of "issue" are you facing? Is there any error message given?

Comment: thanks all, in fact I didn't know '+' is for sqlserver. I use concat and it is work